# How to print variable into empty space without pushing the next text on same line further to the right?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console, console-application

So im currently working on a school assignment where im supposed to make a console version of the old game Jeopardy(using visual studio) but ive come across an issue im not sure how to fix.

Thing is im have an array with categories and 5 variables(kat1+2+3+4+5) to select these categories at random. Problem is the name of the categories differ in length and as so my supreme designed category table doesn't fit anymore. Anyone have any tips as to how i print a variable into "empty" spaces without pushing the | to the right?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|  "+kat1+"  | "+kat2+"   |   "+kat3+" | "+kat4+"   |   "+kat5+"   |");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|            |            |            |            |            |");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|            |            |            |            |            |");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|            |            |            |            |            |");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|            |             |           |            |     |");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("|            |             |           |            |          |");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Wow i spent so much time setting it op nicely and it comes out like this -.-

Comment: you should definitely try *not* to use spaces and tabs whenever possible, but if that is your only option, you can find plenty of tips on lining up characters and such under ascii art.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into string formatting.

```
string result = string.Format("{0}: {1:0.0} - {2:yyyy}",
    value1,
    value2,
    value3);
// Write the result.
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

From http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try! :D

Comment: specifically, you can generate left or right padding